# Function that checks if a string occurs in another string

Tags: python, string, function

I'm currently reading and doing each and every of the exercises in John Guttag's Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python. One particular problem I cannot solve for the life of me:

> Write a function `isIn` that accepts two strings as arguments and
>   returns `True` if either string occurs anywhere in the other, and `False`
>   otherwise. Hint: you might want to use the built-in str operation `in`.

I went through every discussion I could find here, tried with both `in` and `find`, constantly changing something in the code, but every time I would run my program to check if `'abc'` occurs in `'efg'` the answer would be `True`.

Any idea how to solve it? Again, I need to write a function, not simply go with in like:

```
x='abc'

y='efg'

if x in y:

    # Blah

else:

    # another Blah
```

The code I wrote (I'm adding this as apparently some would like to see it) was basically this:

```
def isIn(x,y):

    if x in y or y in x:

        return True

    else:

        return False

a='abc'

b='efg'

isIn(a,b)

if True:

    print "True"

else:

    print "False"
```

Comment: `def check(x, y): return x in y or y in x` ?

Comment: The exercise asks you to write a function named `isIn`, so why doesn't the code in your question contain such a function? :puzzled:

Comment: my code ( I didn't include it as it's wrong) was basically this:

def isIn(x,y):

    if x in y or y in x:

        return True

    else:

        return False
a='abc'
b='efg'
isIn(a,b)
if True:
    print "True"
else:
    print "False"
Sorry, I still cannot copy it here the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the impression that you are a newcomer to Python, so here is the solution to your problem below laid out just as the question asks :)

```
def isIn(string_1, string_2): #This is the function that returns true/false

    if (string_1 in string_2) or (string_2 in string_1):
        is_in = True
    else:
        is_in = False

    return is_in


if __name__ == "__main__":
    string_1 = input ("String 1 here: ")
    string_2 = input ("string 2 here: ")

    is_in = isIn(string_1, string_2) #Calls function with strings as parameters
    print (is_in) #Prints the evaluation of the function after it has run
```

The problem with your code was that you say `if True`, but you aren't giving it anything to check against. `if True` on its own is always true.

If you want me to explain how this code works in more detail I'd be happy to do so :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are completely ignoring the return value of the function `isIn`, and the reason why you always get `True` printed by the code is that the condition you are checking in the `if` statement is the boolean constant `True`, which is of course always `True`.

Try changing your code to:

```
a='abc'
b='efg'
r = isIn(a,b)

if r:
    print "True"
else:
    print "False"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put:

```
x=input('Enter string #1: ')  
y=input('Enter string #2: ')  
#can also just define x and y separately in the console and invoke the   
#    function on those values  

def isIn(x,y):  
    if x in y:  
       return True  
    elif y in x:  
        return True 
    else:   
        return 'False'  

print(isIn(x,y)) #invokes and prints the results of the function evaluating   
#the x and y the user inputs; otherwise nothing is returned
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I eventually did :)

Answer (score 0):

you are not printing the `isIn(x,y)`

```
def is_in(x,y):
    if x in y or y in x:
        return True
    else:
        return False
print(is_in("hello","hello world"))
```

try this :)